# XPATH LOCATOR FOR A ELEMENT LISTED IN AN AUTOCOMPLETE SEARCH

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need to click a random element listed from an autocomplete search of a city. I start typing Welling.. 
and a list of results are displayed. I need to click always a different value from the list

Which Xpath query can I build for my click command??

```html
<input id="fvgkt6ii1a" name="localitysearch" placeholder="Start typing..." autocomplete="none" class="c-input u-pad-r--8" required="" type="text" value="WELLIN">
<div class="c-autocomplete__dropdown c-autocomplete__dropdown--open ">
  <ul class="c-autocomplete__list">
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="WELLINGTON CENTRAL WELLINGTON 6011">WELLINGTON CENTRAL WELLINGTON 6011</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="WELLINGTON HARBOUR (PORT NICHOLSON)">WELLINGTON HARBOUR (PORT NICHOLSON)</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1072">MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1072</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1062">MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1062</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1060">MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1060</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1051">MOUNT WELLINGTON AUCKLAND 1051</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="BREAKER BAY WELLINGTON 6022">BREAKER BAY WELLINGTON 6022</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="HATAITAI WELLINGTON 6021">HATAITAI WELLINGTON 6021</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="HATAITAI WELLINGTON 6011">HATAITAI WELLINGTON 6011</button></li>
    <li class="c-autocomplete__item"><button type="button" class="c-autocomplete__button" aria-label="HOROKIWI WELLINGTON 5016">HOROKIWI WELLINGTON 5016</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Code trials please...

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is to generate a list of numbers between 1 and 10 (unique values). Then pass the first value of the list in the XPath expression. If you need to click multiple times (each time on a different button element), you can increment `i` value later (`i = i+1`).

Something like :

```
import random
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

i = 0
gen = random.sample(list(range(1,11)), k=10)
j = gen[i]

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//ul[@class='c-autocomplete__list']//button[contains(.,'WELLIN')])[%s]"% str(j)))).click()
```